# When I want to abbreviate two words I get error

Tags: java, string

I want to abbreviate names that given names include 3 names or more.
Also, I want to put '.' between them.
Thank you

For example
`sam harris dorothy`
my expectation output like below
`s.h.d`

My code like this

```
    public class AbbreviateTwoWords {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String shs = abbrevName("Sam Harris");
            System.out.println(shs);
        }

        public static String abbrevName(String name) {
        
            String[] splitnamelist = name.split(" ");
            char[] shortform = new char[10];
            String point = ".";
        
            int initial = 0;
            for (String i : splitnamelist) {
                if (initial % 2 == 0) {
                    shortform[initial] = i.charAt(0);
        
                    initial++;
                } else {
                    shortform[initial]=point;
                    initial++;
                }

                return new String(shortform);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You state that you see an error -- what error are you getting? The full message helps

Answer (score 1):

why complicate and use char array, im guessing its something with the indexes at any rate just use string and concatenate:

```
 public static String abbrevName(String name) {
            
         String[]splitnamelist=name.split(" ");
         String shortform="";
 
         
         for (String currentName:splitnamelist) {
             shortform=shortform+currentName.charAt(0);
             shortform=shortform+".";
         }
          //remove the last dot
         if (shortform.length()>0)
         {
         shortform=shortform.substring(0, shortform.length()-1);
         }
         return shortform;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AbbreviateName {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AbbreviateName shs = new AbbreviateName();
        shs.abbrevName("sam harris dorothy");
        
    }

        public void abbrevName(String name) {

            String splitName[] = name.split(" "), seperatedName="";
            int i=0; // To remove the last "+" sign.

            for(String key : splitName){
                seperatedName+=key;
                if(i<splitName.length-1) {
                    seperatedName += "+";
                }
                i++;
            }

            int k;
            System.out.print(seperatedName.charAt(0)+".");
            //First letter always displayed

            for(int j = 0,l=0; j<seperatedName.length()-1; j++){

                k=j;
                if(seperatedName.charAt(j)=='+'){
                    System.out.print(seperatedName.charAt(++k)+".");
                    // Letter succeeding "+" will be printed.

                }
            }
           

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use Java 8+ streams, you could create abbreviations like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Main {
    public static String abbreviate(String input) {
        if (null == input || input.isEmpty()) {
            // nothing to abbreviate
            return input;
        }
        return Arrays.stream(input.split("[.\\s]+")) // split input line by 1 or more whitespaces or dot
                     .map(s -> s.substring(0, 1)) // get first letter
                     .collect(Collectors.joining(".")); // join letters into string with "." delimiter
    }
}
```

In this code a dot `"."` is also included into delimiters to properly handle an abbreviation existing in the input string.

Test and [online demo](https://onlinegdb.com/SJDFZnQeD):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] inputs = {
            "Jerome K. Jerome",
            "Robert Louis Stevenson",
            "Charles Lutwidge Dodgeson"
        };
        
        for (String s : inputs) {
            System.out.printf("'%s' -> '%s'%n", s, abbreviate(s));
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
'Jerome K. Jerome' -> 'J.K.J'                                                                                                                        
'Robert Louis Stevenson' -> 'R.L.S'                                                                                                                  
'Charles Lutwidge Dodgeson' -> 'C.L.D'
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Java8`, we can do this in a few lines.

```
String shs = "sam harris dorothy";
String shortform = Arrays.stream(shs.split(" "))
        .map(s -> s.substring(0, 1))
        .map(s -> s.concat("."))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

This is the output:

```
System.out.println(shortform); //Output is: s.h.d.
System.out.println(shortform.substring(0, shortform.length()-1)); //Output is: s.h.d
```